# debug Xcode exception breakpoint; exception not logged - redux

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, llvm, lldb

When I hit an exception while running in the debugger on device (also simulator?) the exception is never logged for me and I can't find the register that contains the exception.

I'm running Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e) on Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C1510). I almost always test on device...

I've seen similar posts to this while searching the web; here is a summary of what I found and tried without success:

[simulator]

`po (NSException *)$eax OR (NSException *)$rax`

[device]

`po (NSException *)$r0 OR (NSException *)$x0`

I've also seen people say you must enable zombies …

--

My only workaround is for a code line that consistently crashes; I wrap that line in a @try:@catch and add a breakpoint in the catch. I can then print the exception. This is not a good workflow solution and is not possible in many situations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a breakpoint for all exceptions in your breakpoint tab. The app should stop when it hits an exception and you can trace your stack up to find the error.[image]

Comment: It does not display the error. I can see an exception was thrown on the stack but not the exception itself or the exception reason.

Comment: @SeanRoehnelt get rid of your try catch statement. You don't need the stack trace to be able to figure out why. Look at your instance variables etc., it should be obvious usually.